# How to repair the GRUB menu for Kubuntu after re-installing Windows 11

Tags: grub2, kubuntu

I have re-installed Windows 11 on my hard disk in a separate partition and cannot log in to Kubuntu without the GRUB menu being repaired.

Comment: What computer is it (brand name and model)? Can you get into the UEFI/BIOS menus and/or a temporary UEFI/BIOS boot menu? Then you might find a way to boot into Kubuntu, at least temporarily, and maybe even change a setting that brings you back to booting into Kubuntu (where you might run `sudo update-grub` to cater for Windows 11). Otherwise I suggest that you boot Kubuntu live (from USB) and from there run `sudo grub-install` with appropriate parameters (to point at the correct drive and boot directory). In UEFI mode you need the package grub-efi (instead of grub-pc for legacy boot mode).

Comment: Line 209 shows the /EFI/ubuntu/grub file trying to boot from an UUID that does not exist. It looks like only ext4 partition is on sda4. Did Windows install delete your Ubuntu install on NMVe drive?  Be sure to boot in UEFI boot mode.

Comment: I just realised that the computer shop chose the wrong partition and installed Windows over Kubuntu and thereby destroying all my files. Sorry to have bothered you guys.